# Puling a value from a Text file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, blackberry

I have a script that is supposed to reach out to a server and update a value for a user. Right now I can get that script to do it for a single user but I am trying to get it so that it will do it for multiple users from a text file. The script has three functions, the first creates the connection to the server, the second search for the user, and pulls the users GUID from the server's database, and the third set the user's value.

I have tried to update the getuser function so that it pulls the user data from a text file using get-content and then for foreach-object but when I run the script it continues to ask for an email address then errors out.

Here are the snippets from the getuser and the main functions. If anyone has any suggestion I would greatly appreciate it.

```
function getUser($email)
{

   $methodName = "getUser()";
   enterMethod($methodName);
   $response = $null;

   <# Create and set the headers for the REST request #>
   $headers = @{}
   $headers.add("Authorization", $global:authString);
   $headers.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.blackberry.users-v1+json");



   $request = $global:uemBaseUrl + "/users?query=emailAddress=" + $email;


   # Invoke RESTMethod to call users API to obtain users in the system
   try
   {
       $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers $headers -Uri $request;
       if (($response.users -ne $null) -and ($response.users.length -eq 1))
       {
           Write-Host([string]::Format("User with email address '{0}' was found", $email));
       }
       else
       {
           Write-Host([string]::Format("User with email address '{0}' not found", $email));
           exit(1);
       }
   }
   catch
   {
        handleError $_;
   }
   exitMethod($methodName);
   return $response;
} 

     function main
{
    $methodName = "main()";
    enterMethod($methodName);
    try
    {
        if (setup)
        {
            $getUserResponse = get-content .\users.txt $emailaddress;
            $getUserResponse = ForEach-Object 
            $userGUID = $getUserResponse.users.guid;
            if($actionType -eq "Set")
            {
                if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($expiry))
                {
                    throw [System.ArgumentNullException]"The expiry argument is required when actionType=Set";
                }
                if(setActivationpassword($userGUID))
                {
                    Write-Host([string]::Format("Random activation password has been set for user '{0}'", $emailAddress));
                }
            }
            elseif($actionType -eq "ReplaceAll")
            {
                if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($expiry))

                {
                    throw [System.ArgumentNullException]"The expiry argument is required when actionType=ReplaceAll";
                }
                if(replaceActivationpassword($userGUID))
                {
                    Write-Host([string]::Format("Activation password has been replaced for user '{0}'. Existing passwords have been expired.", $emailAddress ));
                }
            }
            elseif($actionType -eq "ExpireAll")
            {
                if(expireActivationpasswords($userGUID))
                {
                    Write-Host([string]::Format("All activation passwords expired for user '{0}'", $emailAddress));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        handleError $_;
    }
    exitMethod($methodName);
    Write-Host("Complete!");
    exit(0);
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the full working Script. This script allows you to do one user at a time.

```
 <#
.DESCRIPTION
    Authenticate and call either "Set", "Expire all" or "Replace" activation passwords for user BWS REST API depending what actionType is used.
.PARAMETER uemHostAndPort
    Host and port of the UEM.
.PARAMETER tenantGuid
    tenantGuid to use for authentication.
.PARAMETER authType
    Authentication type to use.  (Local or AD).
.PARAMETER username
    username to use for authentication.
.PARAMETER password
    password to use for authentication.
.PARAMETER domain
    domain to use for authentication if authType=AD.
.PARAMETER actionType
    Action to perform. (Set, ExpireAll or ReplaceAll)
.PARAMETER emailAddress
    Email address of the user to perform the action on.
.PARAMETER expiry
    The date and time the activation password will expire in ISO-8601 format.
#>

Param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="UEM Host and port."
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$uemHostAndPort,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="Tenant guid to authenticate with."
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$tenantGuid,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="Choose (AD | Local) authType."
    )]
    [ValidateSet('AD', 'Local')]
    [string]$authType,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="Username to authenticate with."
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$username,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="Password to authenticate with."
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$password,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$false
    )]
    [string]$domain,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="Choose (Set | ExpireAll | ReplaceAll) actionType."
    )]
    [ValidateSet('Set', 'ExpireAll', 'ReplaceAll')]
    [string]$actionType,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="User email address to add or remove from group."
    )]
    [string]$emailAddress,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage="The date and time the activation password will expire in ISO-8601 format."
    )]
    [string]$expiry
)

$global:authString = $null;
$global:uemBaseUrl = $null;


<#
    * Generate authorization header required to perform the REST call.
    *
    * @return
    *       True if successful, false otherwise.
#>
function setup()
{
    $methodName = "setup()";
    enterMethod($methodName);
    $provider = $null;

    $global:uemBaseUrl = "https://" + $uemHostAndPort + "/" + $tenantGuid + "/api/v1";

    # Create and set the headers for the REST request
    $headers = @{}
    $headers.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.blackberry.authorizationrequest-v1+json")

    # Create body for REST call
    $body = @{}
    $body.add("provider",$authType);
    $body.add("username", $username);
    $body.add("password", [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($password)));
    if($authType -eq "AD")
    {
        if(-not($domain))
        {
            throw [System.ArgumentNullException]"The domain argument is required when authType=AD";
        }
        $body.add("domain", $domain);
    }

    $request = $global:uemBaseUrl + "/util/authorization";

    # Invoke RESTMethod to call authorization route to generate the authorization headers
    try
    {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Headers $headers -Uri $request -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json);
        $global:authString = $response
    }
    catch
    {
        handleError $_;
    }

    Write-Host([string]::Format("Authorization header string generated: {0}", $global:authString));
    Write-Host("Setup Complete...");
    exitMethod($methodName);
    return $true;
}

<#
    * Generate authorization header required to perform the REST call.
    *
    * @param email
    *       Email of the user to get.
    * @return
    *       User that was found.
#>
function getUser($email)

{

   $methodName = "getUser()";
   enterMethod($methodName);
   $response = $null;

   <# Create and set the headers for the REST request #>
   $headers = @{}
   $headers.add("Authorization", $global:authString);
   $headers.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.blackberry.users-v1+json");



   $request = $global:uemBaseUrl + "/users?query=emailAddress=" + $email;


   # Invoke RESTMethod to call users API to obtain users in the system
   try
   {
       $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers $headers -Uri $request;
       if (($response.users -ne $null) -and ($response.users.length -eq 1))
       {
           Write-Host([string]::Format("User with email address '{0}' was found", $email));
       }
       else
       {
           Write-Host([string]::Format("User with email address '{0}' not found", $email));
           exit(1);
       }
   }
   catch
   {
        handleError $_;
   }
   exitMethod($methodName);
   return $response;
}

<#
    * Set acctivation password for a user.
    *
    * @param userGuid
    *       Guid of user.
    * @return
    *       True if successful, false otherwise.
#>
function setActivationpassword($userGuid)
{
    $methodName = "setActivationpassword()";
    enterMethod($methodName);


    # Create and set the headers for the REST command
    $headers = @{}
    $headers.add("Authorization", $global:authString);
    $headers.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.blackberry.activationpasswords-v1+json");

    # Create body for REST call
    $body = @{};
    $innerBody = @(@{
    "password" = $null;
    "emailTemplate" = $null;
    "expiry" = $expiry;
    "expireAfterUse" = "true";
    "activationProfile"= $null;
    });
    $body.add("activationPasswords",$innerBody);

    $request = $global:uemBaseUrl + "/users/" + $userGuid + "/activationPasswords";

    # Invoke RESTMethod to set activation password.
    try
    {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Headers $headers -Uri $request -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json);
    }
    catch
    {
         handleError $_;
    }

    exitMethod($methodName);
    return $true;
}

<#
    * Expire all acctivation passwords for a user.
    *
    * @param userGuid
    *       Guid of user.
    * @return
    *       True if successful, false otherwise.
#>
function expireActivationpasswords($userGuid)
{
    $methodName = "expireActivationpasswords()";
    enterMethod($methodName);

    # Create and set the headers for the REST command
    $headers = @{}
    $headers.add("Authorization", $global:authString);
    $headers.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.blackberry.activationpasswords-v1+json");

    $request = $global:uemBaseUrl + "/users/" + $userGuid + "/activationPasswords";

    # Invoke RESTMethod to exipre all activation passwords.
    try
    {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method DELETE -Headers $headers -Uri $request
    }
    catch
    {
         handleError $_;
    }

    exitMethod($methodName);
    return $true;
}

<#
    * Replace all acctivation passwords for a user.
    *
    * @param userGuid
    *       Guid of user.
    * @return
    *       True if successful, false otherwise.
#>
function replaceActivationpassword($userGuid)
{
    $methodName = "replaceActivationpassword()";
    enterMethod($methodName);

    # Create and set the headers for the REST command
    $headers = @{}
    $headers.add("Authorization", $global:authString);
    $headers.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.blackberry.activationpasswords-v1+json");

    # Create body for REST call
    $body = @{};
    $innerBody = @(@{
    "password" = $null;
    "emailTemplate" = $null;
    "expiry" = $expiry;
    "expireAfterUse" = "true";
    "activationProfile"= $null;
    });
    $body.add("activationPasswords",$innerBody);

    $request = $global:uemBaseUrl + "/users/" + $userGuid + "/activationPasswords";

    # Invoke RESTMethod to set activation password.
    try
    {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Headers $headers -Uri $request -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json);
    }
    catch
    {
         handleError $_;
    }

    exitMethod($methodName);
    return $true;
}

<#
    * Logging for method entry.
    *
    * @param methodName
    *       Name of the method to log
#>
function enterMethod($methodName)
{
    Write-Host([string]::Format("Entering {0}...", $methodName));
}

<#
    * Logging for method exit.
    *
    * @param methodName
    *       Name of the method to log.
#>
function exitMethod($methodName)
{
    Write-Host([string]::Format("Exiting {0}...", $methodName));
}

<#

    * Handle any errors that occur when performing the REST call.
    *
    * @param error
    *       The group create context.
#>
function handleError($error)
{
    Write-Error ("The command cound not be completed.  `r`nReason: " + $error.exception.message + " `r`nDetails: "+ $error.errordetails);
    exit(1);
}

function main
{
    $methodName = "main()";
    enterMethod($methodName);
    try
    {
        if (setup)
        {
            $getUserResponse = getuser $emailaddress;
            $userGUID = $getUserResponse.users.guid;
            if($actionType -eq "Set")
            {
                if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($expiry))
                {
                    throw [System.ArgumentNullException]"The expiry argument is required when actionType=Set";
                }
                if(setActivationpassword($userGUID))
                {
                    Write-Host([string]::Format("Random activation password has been set for user '{0}'", $emailAddress));
                }
            }
            elseif($actionType -eq "ReplaceAll")
            {
                if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($expiry))
                {
                    throw [System.ArgumentNullException]"The expiry argument is required when actionType=ReplaceAll";
                }
                if(replaceActivationpassword($userGUID))
                {
                    Write-Host([string]::Format("Activation password has been replaced for user '{0}'. Existing passwords have been expired.", $emailAddress ));
                }
            }
            elseif($actionType -eq "ExpireAll")
            {
                if(expireActivationpasswords($userGUID))
                {
                    Write-Host([string]::Format("All activation passwords expired for user '{0}'", $emailAddress));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        handleError $_;
    }
    exitMethod($methodName);
    Write-Host("Complete!");
    exit(0);
}

# Call main function.
main;
```

Comment: "when I run the script it continues to ask for an email address then errors out." - what does the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
 $getUserResponse = get-content .\users.txt $emailaddress;
 $getUserResponse = ForEach-Object
```

It's going to be hard to debug this without running it but what are you trying to do with this?:

```
$getUserResponse = get-content .\users.txt $emailaddress
```

$emailAddress from what I can see is a never defined. Is the users.txt just a line by line file full of users files?

ForEach-Object would also need data to be piped to.

Comment: So the text file is just a list of user email addresses, the Script takes the email address and locates the user GUID.

Let me seee if I can post the whole script in its working fashion.

Comment: Ah I see so you'd have to do $getUserResponse = Get-Content .\users.txt then do something like $getUserReponse | Foreach-Object { #Put the code here that checks the API for the Guid}